# Как спрятать шаблон при загрузке AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Делаю простой справочник на данном фреймворке и не могу понять как скрыть все эти {{}} при загрузке? ng-cloak позапихивал всюду куда только можно.[Вот собственно сайт](http://ex3.skyq.ru)

К примеру есть кусок кода. Как видно ng-cloak везде где надо и не надо. Но не помогает.

```
<div ng-cloak ng-repeat="item in staff | filter:search_dep:strict">
<div ng-cloak  class="page-header">
    <h3 ng-cloak>{{item.description}}<span style="float:right;">({{totalmans.length}})</span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) Ну и без кода и того _куда_ ты позапихивал - нельзя ничего сказать

Comment: Цитата из документации по ссылке @Grundy: "For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head section of the html document". А у Вас это совсем не так.

Comment: Точно ведь. Не доглядел

Comment: @Yaant, на самом деле это особо не влияет, директива `ng-cloak` ничего не делает. Просто для нее прописал стиль: `[ng-cloak] {display:none !important;}`. Если стиль подключен - то не важно где подключается скрипт

Comment: @Grundy: Ну так этот стиль ведь прописывает в конце своей инициализации сам angular.js. Соответственно, пока он не загрузится, не будет и стиля (если, конечно, его руками не прописывать в свои .css)

Comment: @Yaant, на самом деле нет. Стиль можно подключать вручную.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да, и я упомянул это в скобках. Но у автора-то он вручную не подключается. :)

Comment: @Yaant, есть специальный файл: [_angular-csp.css_](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) в свои css ничего не надо прописывать

Comment: @Grundy, да, но я же не поленился заглянуть на сайт автора, и он не использует CSP mode, :)